# Improve this Query (Sum of past sales to date by line)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to improve on this query. It's from a MUCH larger table, but I've taken the essentials and whittled it down to the problem below. This table gives us sales for a given month, store and product group. I need, for each line (i.e. month/store/product combination), the sum of sales over the previous TWO and FOUR months up to that date.

What I have below works fine in terms of giving correct values, but it's a performance hog on a large table. I looked into the OVER clause with PRECEDING/FOLLOWING constraints, but I'm using SQL Server 2008 which doesn't support those. Do you see a more optimal way to rewrite this and give the same desired result? Thanks.

```
create table #sales_by_month 
(
    period int, --YYYYMM
    store varchar(8), --store number
    product_group varchar(8),
    sales int
)

insert into #sales_by_month values (201701, 51, 'shoes', 12)
insert into #sales_by_month values (201701, 51, 'clothes', 15)
insert into #sales_by_month values (201701, 12, 'shoes', 10)
insert into #sales_by_month values (201701, 12, 'clothes', 9)
insert into #sales_by_month values (201702, 51, 'shoes', 0)
insert into #sales_by_month values (201702, 51, 'clothes', 20)
insert into #sales_by_month values (201702, 12, 'shoes', 30)
insert into #sales_by_month values (201702, 12, 'clothes', 8)
insert into #sales_by_month values (201703, 51, 'shoes', 7)
insert into #sales_by_month values (201703, 51, 'clothes', 4)
insert into #sales_by_month values (201703, 12, 'shoes', 21)
insert into #sales_by_month values (201703, 12, 'clothes', 0)
insert into #sales_by_month values (201704, 51, 'shoes', 50)
insert into #sales_by_month values (201704, 51, 'clothes', 4)
insert into #sales_by_month values (201704, 12, 'shoes', 16)
insert into #sales_by_month values (201704, 12, 'clothes', 20)
insert into #sales_by_month values (201705, 51, 'shoes', 21)
insert into #sales_by_month values (201705, 51, 'clothes', 17)
insert into #sales_by_month values (201705, 12, 'shoes', 0)
insert into #sales_by_month values (201705, 12, 'clothes', 5)

select 
    period, 
    store, 
    product_group, 
    (select sum(sales) 
     from #sales_by_month x2 
     where x2.store = #sales_by_month.store 
       and x2.product_group = #sales_by_month.product_group 
       and left(x2.period, 4) * 12 + right(x2.period, 2) 
                between left(#sales_by_month.period, 4) * 12 + right(#sales_by_month.period, 2) - 1
                    and left(#sales_by_month.period, 4) * 12 + right(#sales_by_month.period, 2) ) sales_to_date_last_2_months,
    (select sum(sales) 
     from #sales_by_month x4
     where x4.store = #sales_by_month.store 
       and x4.product_group = #sales_by_month.product_group 
       and left(x4.period, 4) * 12 + right(x4.period, 2) 
               between left(#sales_by_month.period, 4) * 12 + right(#sales_by_month.period, 2) - 3
                   and left(#sales_by_month.period, 4) * 12 + right(#sales_by_month.period, 2)) sales_to_date_last_4_months
from 
    #sales_by_month

--drop table #sales_by_month
```

Comment: The biggest issue I see here is all the non-SARGable predicates in your subqueries. When wrap columns in a function like that it means no indexes can be utilized. This is why we like to use proper datatypes. Adding a computed column with a datatype of date would probably help in a lot of situations here. But for this query I think you could make this a little simpler.

Comment: @SeanLange - Do you mean a proper data type on period? Then work with the native date calculation functions (DATEADD(), DATEDIFF()) instead of all the math to make the BETWEEN clause work?

Comment: That is exactly what I mean. And then all your date calculations would be against GETDATE and the stored date value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window clauses with `sum()` starting in SQL Server 2012.  Assuming you have data for each month and store

```
select sbm.*,
       sum(sales) over (partition by store, productgroup 
                        order by period
                        rows between 4 preceding and 2 preceding
                       ) as sales_2_4
from #sales_by_month sbm;
```

That doesn't work in SQL Server 2008.  I would recommend `apply`:

```
with sbm as (
      select sbm.*,
              row_number() over (partition by store, productgroup order by period) as seqnum
      from #sales_by_month sbm
     )
select sbm.*, sbm2.sales_2_4
from sbm outer apply
     (select sum(sbm2.sales) as sales_2_4
      from sbm sbm2
      where sbm2.store = sbm.store and sbm2.productgroup = sbm2.productgroup and
            sbm2.seqnum between sbm.seqnum - 4 and sbm.seqnum - 2
     ) sbm2
```

Comment: This is interesting and I'm going to try it... But is there anything intrinsic about it to suggest that it will be faster than my query?

Comment: @bvy . . . Probably not much faster for a single column.  However, you can calculate both sales quantities in a single subquery using `apply`, and that would be only one pass through the table for two columns, rather than one pass per column.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,period),1,4) +'-'+ SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,period),5,2) + N'-01')periodDt 
,DATEADD(MONTH,2,CONVERT(DATE,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,period),1,4) +'-'+ SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,period),5,2) + N'-01'))periodDt2 
,DATEADD(MONTH,4,CONVERT(DATE,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,period),1,4) +'-'+ SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,period),5,2) + N'-01'))periodDt4 
,* INTO #t1 FROM #sales_by_month 

SELECT periodDt,periodDt2,periodDt4,period,store,product_group, SUM(sales)sales INTO #t2 FROM #t1 GROUP BY periodDt,periodDt2,periodDt4,period,store,product_group

SELECT ISNULL([2m].store,[4m].store),ISNULL([2m].product_group,[4m].product_group),ISNULL(sales2month,0),ISNULL(sales4month,0)  FROM 
(SELECT store,product_group,sales sales2month FROM #t2 WHERE perioddt2 >= GETDATE())[2m]
FULL JOIN 
(SELECT store,product_group,sales sales4month FROM #t2 WHERE perioddt4 >= GETDATE())[4m]
ON [2m].store = [4m].store AND [2m].product_group = [4m].product_group
```

Comment: Thank you. Temp tables aren't an option in the environment I'm working in. It's possible I could use CTE's but don't know if that would give me any performance gains. I'll look more closely at your answer.